# Browser Extensions/Add-ons size limit

Tags: javascript, browser, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I need to add few (from one to hundreds) files in my extensions(firefox/chrome/safari). Files can be from 10mb to 100mb size.
That a the limit size of extension?
I found only limit for Google Web Store extensions. It's 10mb. Is it limit for all .crx extensions?

Answer (score 2):

I would be very surprised if there were any artificial limits imposed on extension size, doing this makes no sense. But you will have to try it to be certain - I can only tell you that Firefox quite definitely doesn't set any artificial limits. There will be technical limits of course but the lowest one will probably be the 4 GB boundary.

Now if you want to *host* an extension somewhere, be it Google Web Store or Mozilla Add-ons site - you will most likely see much lower limits. Neither Google nor Mozilla will be too interested in offering huge extensions for download. You apparently found the limit for Google Web Store already. I don't think that the Mozilla Add-ons site explicitly defines the limit but an insanely large extension will most likely be rejected in the review process.

Comment: This is correct: Chrome doesn't itself apply any limit to CRX sizes. That said, I don't think anyone on the team has really tested extreme package sizes. You might run into slowness, or even crashes. I'd suggest looking into alternative mechanism of storing large amounts of data. The [FileSystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) for example, is an excellent option.